# How to print SFSafariViewController full web page?

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am opening a pdf file in `SFSafariViewController`. Now I want to print this PDF from `SFSafariViewController`.

But Share button of safari view controller does not have print option.

Please tell me how to add print functionality to `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: Could you be able to find any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can custom activity.

```
    extension ViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
        func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, activityItemsFor URL: URL, title: String?) -> [UIActivity] {
            let acitivity = CustomActivity()
            return [acitivity]
        }

        func printURL(url: URL) {
        }
    }
```

CustomActivity.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomActivity: UIActivity {
    override class var activityCategory: UIActivityCategory {
        return .action
    }

    override var activityType: UIActivityType? {
        return UIActivityType.print
    }

    override var activityTitle: String? {
        return "Print"
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return nil
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func perform() {
        // do something here
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: it is not working for me . Is there any need to write something in func printURL(url: URL) {}

Comment: not working when you press icon print ?? don't forget add delegate for SFSafariViewController